# Printing a names in java?

Tags: java

Can you tell me how to solve that problem ?

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

```
 package Exercise2501;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Friends
    {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
          int number = scanner.nextInt();
          for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
          {   
          System.out.println("Type a few names. ");
          String names = scanner.nextLine();
          }
          String names = scanner.nextLine();
          System.out.println(names);


       }

    }
```

Comment: what do u require..Your question is not clear.can u give in detail

Comment: When i try to run the code it asks me how many names do i want to print and then just prints "Type a few names" that many times

Comment: Move the line before for loop

Comment: Edit the code and add what is you are trying and what is your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    package Exercise2501;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Friends {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      //Get the number of entries 
      System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
      int number = scanner.nextInt();
      //create an array with that number
      String names[] = new names[number];
      //Ask the user to enter the Names
      System.out.println("Type a few names. ");
      //Store the names in the array
      for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
      {   
          names[i] = scanner.nextLine();
      }
      //Do the remaining you want
    }

    }
```